# UnicodeDecodeError Python

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to build up a network using Networkx library in python. Some of the node names are url links.
For example, one of the urls are 'http://www.everydayhealth.com/health-recipe/summer-vegetable-cr+\x8cpes.aspx?pos=3'

I am trying to save the network in gml format and it gives me the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 111: ordinal not in range(128)

Based on the links I read, I know that the url is a 'string' and not a 'unicode'. I checked it using type(url). But because it gives me the above error it means it does not contain all ASCII characters. So, I tried the following:

u1=url.decode('ascii')
It gives me the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 64: ordinal not in range(128)

How should I go about it?
My main purpose is to save this network in a gml format. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to change encoding?
this may help you https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: I did unicode(url, errors='ignore') and it worked. 
Thank you